# How to make a timer that reload your consoleapplication C#?

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in coding C#, and for my first program I want to have a timer that reloads my Console Application every 10 seconds.  Is it possible? Can you write an example please?

Comment: If this is your first program, I would start with "Hello World", or whatever a good tutorial or programming book tells you.

Comment: "hello world" programs wouldn't be useful for programmers that have experience in other languages.

Comment: If you really need to run your program at a set interval, just set up a scheduled task on the machine which runs your program repeatedly at the desired interval.

Comment: "What are you trying to accomplish by restarting the app? –  Grant Winney 5 mins ago" I need to have a program that works on his own.

Comment: `I need to have a program that works on his own` WUT i am so confused

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "reloading" the application, you'd typically have a TImer trigger a specific routine within your application on a regular interval.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting timer");             
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimer;;

        timer.Enabled = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to shut down");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void OnTimer(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This code will run every 10 seconds
        Console.WriteLine("In timer");
    }
}
```